# Need Help for grouping in Report

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm developing a report and I need to group(row grouping) it according to parameters which will pass from customer's desire.

For example,

```
[CustomerName] [Product]
[Group]
[aa]           [computer]
[bb]           [mouse]
```

What I want is that "Group" will be parameters and when the user wants to group with "customername", Group will represent as CustomerName and group according to "CustomerName". Actually I have many columns in my table and I really need this for my project.

Thanks a lot,
Doyle Raymond

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with LINQ.

```
var someOrderedListOfCustomers = GetCustomerList().GroupBy(x => x.CustomerName);
```

Obviously your report will have to know how to handle this enumerable, but that's true of any enumerable.

If you want to do this through reflection then you'll need to use reflection to get the list of possible parameters and let the user select which one they want to group by.

Comment: there are altogether six radio buttons which users wish to group with.. btw, don't i do anything with UI ?? i mean do i have to add parameters for that or change sth in UI ?? and i'm urgently needing... pls reply me ASAP.. thanks a lot

Comment: i tested it but it doesn't work... i've IList and when i get a query, i've got 3 records... but after grouping, there's null all i've got... :(